# Create a branch from the branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Let’s say branch A is a created from trunk. The branch A is in testing stage.  Now there is a new project and will be release after branch A. However the project must start and cannot wait the branch A to be released. There is a big change in branch A and branch B is a few changes. I want to create a branch B from branch A. When branch A is release, it merge to the trunk. After branch B is completed and released, the branch B merge to the branch A and then Branch A merge back to trunk. Is it possible in TFS to merge trunk as the above approach?

Answer (score 2):

TFVC branches are hierarchal. You can do a baseless merge, but that typically indicates a failure in your branching strategy.

The "modern" approach is to minimize the number of branches you create (or eliminate branches entirely) and instead rely on feature toggles to isolate work-in-progress, so that your codebase is always integrated.